# django-admin.py startproject returns Could not import settings 'settings'

Tags: python, django

```
virtualenv ./env
source ./env/bin/activate
pip install Django
django-admin.py startproject src
```

And i get an error "
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings"

I use MacOs.
Python version is 2.7.6.

```
username-Pro:project_1 username$ virtualenv env/
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
username-Pro:project_1 username$ source env/bin/activate
(env)username-Pro:project_1 username$ pip install -U setuptools pip
Downloading/unpacking setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-7.0.tar.gz#md5=6245d6752e2ef803c365f560f7f2f940
  Downloading setuptools-7.0.tar.gz (793kB): 793kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package setuptools

Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.6.tar.gz#md5=01026f87978932060cc86c1dc527903e
  Downloading pip-1.5.6.tar.gz (938kB): 938kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pip

    warning: no files found matching 'pip/cacert.pem'
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  Found existing installation: setuptools 0.6c11
    Uninstalling setuptools:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools
  Running setup.py install for setuptools

    Installing easy_install script to /Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/bin
    Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/bin
  Found existing installation: pip 1.3.1
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
  Running setup.py install for pip

    warning: no files found matching 'pip/cacert.pem'
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
    Installing pip script to /Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/bin
    Installing pip2.7 script to /Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/bin
    Installing pip2 script to /Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/bin
Successfully installed setuptools pip
Cleaning up...
(env)username-Pro:project_1 username$ pip install Django
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Downloading Django-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB): 7.4MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: Django
Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...
(env)username-Pro:project_1 username$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.7.1
(env)username-Pro:project_1 username$ django-admin.py startproject src
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/project_1/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings
(env)username-Pro:project_1 username$
```

Comment: Does the following command work ? python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"

Comment: yes. It returns "1.7.1".

Comment: This is strange... very strange. This error is thrown when you already have a project and paths are not set...

Comment: Could you try the following : after creating the virtualenv, do source env/bin/activate, do pip install -U setuptools pip. Then install django

Comment: I did what you say. But nothing is changed.

Comment: Can you compare the outputs of your console to this one, I just tried the same thing : http://pastebin.com/H1ZJbB9M

Comment: I add the outputs of my console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65983/discussion-between-user2120409-and-pierre-alex).

Answer (score 9):

You probably had settings env var from a previous project.

```
$ unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```